# Only static members can accessed in initializes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have issue in set my List variable(_tasks) with a method(readSavedTasks) being called to setup for the values. Here's the code line that have the error.

```
Future<List<ListTasks>> readSavedTasks() async {
   List<ListTasks> tasksSaved = await DataStorage().readTasks();
   return Future.value(tasksSaved);
}

List<ListTasks> _tasks = readSavedTasks();
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: `readSavedTasks()` returns a `Future...` so you either need `_tasks` to be of the same type as the return, or to resolve its value, by completing the async call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use non-static members in initialisation. This is a better approach:

```
Future<List<ListTasks>> readSavedTasks() async {
  List<ListTasks> tasksSaved = await DataStorage().readTasks();
  return Future.value(tasksSaved);
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _init();
}

Future<void> _init() async {
  List<ListTasks> _tasks = await readSavedTasks();
}
```